# Using IComponentContext to register new component

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, autofac

Given an existing object instance how to register a new Type using the IComponentContext?

I can do it reality using the builder like this:

```
var userSession = new UserSession();

builder.Register(x => userSession).As<UserSession>().InstancePerRequest();
```

But how to do it using the IComponentContext

```
var registration = RegistrationBuilder.ForType<UserSession>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest().CreateRegistration();

ComponentContext.ComponentRegistry.Register(registration);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var registration = RegistrationBuilder
                       .ForDelegate<UserSession>((c, p) => userSession)
                       .ExternallyOwned()
                       .AsSelf()
                       .InstancePerRequest()
                       .CreateRegistration();
componentContext.ComponentRegistry.Register(registration);
```

Comment: Event tho I ended up going a different route, It works thanks :)